# Binary coding for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas table with coding like this:

```
id var1 var2 var3
1   1    3    4
2   2    5
3   1    2
```

An would like to have it converted to binary like this

```
id x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
1  1  0  1  1  0
2  0  1  0  0  1
3  1  1  0  0  0
```

So effectively mapping each variable's position.

Answer (score 2):

Use `get_dummies`

```
In [506]: (pd.get_dummies(df.filter(like='var').stack())
             .sum(level=0).rename(columns='x{:.0f}'.format))
Out[506]:
   x1  x2  x3  x4  x5
0   1   0   1   1   0
1   0   1   0   0   1
2   1   1   0   0   0
```